# Remove square bracket with inner content in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I remove all characters starting from a square bracket in JavaScript or jQuery?

For example: `name[required]` becomes `name`.

Comment: `[]` is not curly bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'name[required]'.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '')
// => "name"
```